# The php if(isset($_GET['something'])) is not working

Tags: php, isset

I tried my best to figure out how to redirect someone based on the `index.php?ref=[link]` , searched the internet... And couldn't figure out, here is my code :

```
if(isset($_GET['ref'])){
    header("Location: /" . $_GET['ref']);
}else if(empty($_GET['ref'])){
    header('Location: /welcome/');
}else{
    header('Location: /welcome/');
}
```

It always executes the `else if` one, even if the value in `?ref` is set.
Anyone can help?

Comment: Well, if NOT SET, it's always empty.. Now, why it's not set in the first place, I don't know. Edit: to elaborate, your else alone is useless.

Comment: When for example I set it to ?ref=websites , it executes the else if one.

Comment: That I got. I don't know why that's happening. What I meant is that your `else` section is never going to be reached.

Comment: Are you using any framework? Any Request wrapper? Are you 100% sure, that url with ?ref in it is typo-free? Can you please dump `$_GET` for us?

Comment: Are you 100% sure, that you are viewing right file? :) And if so, are you sure you have saved your changes to it? Can you show us whole file instead of just those few lines?

Answer (score 0):

My shot - `isset` determine if a variable is set and is not NULL. So if your url contains just `?ref` (not `?ref=subpage`) the condition is met, however you will be redirected to `header("Location: /" . NULL);`.

Try using `!empty()` instead of `isset()`.

BTW: Always add `exit` after `header("Location: ...")`

Comment: Just a note: if the url is just `?ref`, the variable would be an empty string (`string(0) ""`), not `null`, so `isset($_GET['ref'])` would be `true`, and the redirection would be to `header("Location: /" . "");`. (In the end, appending null or empty string to a string gives the same results, anyways xD)

Comment: @FirstOne Yup, that's true. `NULL` in this case was casted to empty string and concatted with rest of the string. I was just not sure if `Location: /` was where you want to go.

Comment: I'll try that solution.

Comment: Can you please dump $_GET for us from the moment, when ref `isset($_GET['ref'])` is set? Try `var_export($_GET);`

Comment: I thought of another way to do that and it worked, thanks guys!

Comment: Glad to hear. Can you share your new approach with us?